# How can I change the title of the document during .ready()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am using some nested layouts in Ruby on Rails, and in one of the layouts i have a need to read in a string from a div and set that as the title of the document. What is correct way (if any) to set the title of the document?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    // ???

});
</script>
```

Comment: Just an explanation for the ones wondering for why not just setting the title tag serverside: Sometimes the page is generated with content and action mixed. I.e. you might have an incude-file first, which makes the header, then the content is being pulled from a database, e.g. customer name.
Which means at the time the title has been sent, the customer name is not known. It is sloppy coding not separating business logic and presentation, get all data first, then displauy it, but sometimes that's what you have. Boss: "Just put the customername in the title" You "I have to refactor all code."

Answer (score 321, accepted):

The following should work but it wouldn't be SEO compatible. It's best to put the title in the title tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        document.title = 'blah';
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Wouldn't any javascript-generated HTML be SEO incompatible? I'm pretty sure googlebot doesn't execute javascript...

Comment: I've read that there's ways to tell Google Bot what to read when your pages is made with Ajax... trying googling around.

Comment: @trusktr: I think you're talking about this Google-article: [Making AJAX Applications Crawlable](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/). But it has NOTHING to do with this kind of problem, so Orion Edwards is right. It's just a method to let Google read contents that are normally generated with AJAX, via HTML snapshots and some server side modifications.

Comment: Using html text in the title is not working. Say I use <span class="test"> Blah </span>

Comment: does not work in FF 29.0.1 for me, but this solution described below works: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11171548/1915920

Comment: @OrionEdwards Now, more than five years later, http://www.rimmkaufman.com/blog/googlebot-crawling-javascript-site-ready/03062014/

Comment: @dpan, I am facing a issue by using both `<title>` tag & `document.title` in a single file. When pages loaded, first text written in `<title>` tag load for some nano second after that `document.title` works. If I'll remove `<title>` tag then site url is displaying for some nano second then `document.title` works. I don't want to display the title from `<title>` tag, I want to directly load the tile from `document.title`. Please help.

Comment: @NishantPandya you can see the "original" title for a brief moment because the JS code is executed only on DOM ready. You could remove the `$(document).ready` stuff and just print `document.title = 'blah';`. But, if you can do that, maybe you could just change the `<title>` tag content on server-side..

Answer (score 50):

Do not use `$('title').text('hi')`, because IE doesn't support it.

It is better to use `document.title = 'new title';`

Answer (score 46):

This works fine in all browser...

```
$(document).attr("title", "New Title");
```

Works in IE too

Answer (score 37):

Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    document.title = "Hello World!";
});
```

Be sure to set a default-title if you want your site to be properly indexed by search-engines.

A little tip:

```
$(function ()
{
    // this is a shorthand for the whole document-ready thing
    // In my opinion, it's more readable 
});
```

Comment: You should post the shorthand thing as a new "Question" in itself. Useful!

Comment: Not sure I understand you, MDCore.

Comment: Jeff has suggested one uses stackoverflow for those technical tips that one might put on one's blog. I was suggesting posting the tip as a new question that you answer yourself.

Answer (score 17):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(this).attr("title", "sometitle");

});
</script>
```

Comment: yes, actually, you cannot use `$('title').text(...)` because of [bug in IE](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7825)

Comment: Why not `document.title` ?

Answer (score 7):

document.title was not working for me.

Here is another way to do it using JQuery

```
$('html head').find('title').text("My New Page Title");
```

Comment: for me either (FF 29.0.1) and if there is no `<title>` set up at all, even `$('html head').add('<title>override default title</title>')` does not work

Answer (score 5):

> I am using some nested layouts in Ruby on Rails, and in one of the layouts i have a need to read in a string from a div and set that as the title of the document.

The correct way to do this is on the server side.

In your layout, there at some point will be some code which *puts the text in the div*. Make this code also set some instance variable such as `@page_title`, and then in your outer layout have it do `<%= @page_title || 'Default Title' %>`

Answer (score -2):

If you have got a serverside script get_title.php that echoes the current title session this works fine in jQuery:

```
$.get('get_title.php',function(*respons*){
    title=*respons* + 'whatever you want'   
    $(document).attr('title',title)
})
```

Comment: doing an ajax request for setting the title is very wasteful in my opinion.

Comment: OP specifically requested a jQuery solution to a client-side problem.

Comment: Setting the title via ajax is useful, as it can help to identify the current browser tab for the user when they're on a different page.