# Is there a way, using jQuery, to change the document.title after the page has loaded?

Tags: jquery, html, title

I have coded myself into a corner. Does anyone know the answer? Thanks!

Comment: This is easily found using Google.  What have you tried and what doesn't work?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180103/jquery-how-to-change-title-of-document-during-ready

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will work also:

```
$('title').text("Boo");
```

Comment: Not sure why I couldn't get the document.title or this.title to take, but Vincent's method did the trick. I should've been more specific in what I was doing, I suppose, in my question. I am grabbing the contents of a div near the end of the html body and writing it out to the page title. If I figure out what the problem was I'll post it up here.

Comment: doesn't work in IE8 - "Unexpected call to method or property access."

Comment: This is not a cross browser solution. The `$(document).attr('title', 'new title');` mentioned below is better.

Comment: Any ideas as to how an approach like this might affect Google indexing the site? I know page title is important... Does google include the original page title or the new one?

Answer (score 9):

```
document.title = 'new value';
```

Is this not working for you?

Comment: Strangely no. I can read the value of document.title, but I cannot seem to change the display. I have tried setting it in the head of the document as well as in the body.

Comment: @subbit, Are you sure your browser isn't preventing you from changing the title?  Check your browser's options.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    this.title = 'foo'
})
```

Comment: This helped me. Sometimes (in FF and Chrome), the things is that the stuff is tried even it the site is not fully loaded. Hence, it might not work as expected...

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this will help you:

```
$(document).attr('title', 'new title');
```

Answer (score 1):

`$('title').text("Boo");` is not good idea because **IE8** has problem with that.
this bug is reported [Here](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7339) but jQuery developers did not solve that and their solution is **Use `document.title='Boo';`**.
my idea is that

1. using `document.title` is best option and it is cross browser solution
2. but if you are used to use jQuery you can use `$(document).attr('title', 'new title');`. i tested it and has no problem with major browsers and IE8