# How to change document.title when clicking a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Seems impossible... maybe theres a genius around here!

## jquery only

Comment: "Maybe there's a genius around here!" - made be legitimately spit-take. Good on you, bud!

Comment: Along with @Blender, I'd love to know what you tried.

Comment: Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500554/is-there-a-way-using-jquery-to-change-the-document-title-after-the-page-has-lo?rq=1

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180103/jquery-how-to-change-title-of-document-during-ready?lq=1

Comment: Even http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601163/jquery-change-pages-title-when-user-in-a-different-tab?lq=1

Comment: Might wanna open up your page in Chrome and see the console for errors, then.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need for jQuery. I'm only using it because it's easier to bind events with it:

```
$('#your-link').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  document.title = 'The new title';
});
```

Also, out of curiosity, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('a').click(function(){
  $('head title').text('HelloWorld'); 
 });
});
```

and might need html like this

```
<a href="#">Click here to change title</a>
```