# Use a DIV's Contents as an HTML Page's Title?

Tags: jquery, html, rss, title

I'm building a social media based news site, and for the sharing element to work (Twitter, Facebook etc.), the page's  value must reflect it's "headline" (e.g. when the page is shared online, the title should be "Man Bites Dog", not "My News Site").

I've tried multiple PHP and jQuery solutions, but nothing seems to work. There is a complication, though. The site's content is delivered via RSS feed from Blogger, and I'm using jQuery to parse the "headline" RSS and display it on the page. Since the "headline" content is dynamically generated when the page loads, could this cause the problem?

If so, is there a way to use the same RSS-based method to change the  value?

Here's the code I'm using to aggregate and display the RSS "headline" feed...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        jQuery(function($) {
    $('#headline').rssfeed('http://cjfoote.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss', {
        limit: 1
    });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remember:

If you use JS to change the title a searchrobot cannot read the new title. So it don't effect your SEO.

If you use PHP to change the title it has a positive influence on your SEO.

---

If you want to use PHP, look for [simpleXML](http://php.net/simpleXMLElement) to read the RSS file and then simply [`echo`](http://php.net/echo) the correct headline.

Comment: This sounds like the right method, but I have no idea how to use XML.  I tried a few different PHP echo-ing methods, and tried to echo the contents of the "headline" DIV, but since the DIV is technically empty, it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you are asking how to change the title of the page using jQuery:
[jQuery: how to change title of document during .ready()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180103/jquery-how-to-change-title-of-document-during-ready)

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        document.title = getHeadlineFromFeed();  
      });

      function getHeadlineFromFeed() {
            // your logic for retrieving the rss feed
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: By "logic", do you mean the code I use to aggregate the RSS feed into the "headline" DIV? This is the code:

<script src="js/zrss_rss_headline.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery(function($) {
 $('#headline').rssfeed('http://cjfoote.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss', {
  limit: 1
 });
});

</script>

Comment: yes, you need to get the headline from that element.  maybe something like document.title = $("#headline").text()

Comment: I tried this:

 <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        document.title = rssfeed();  
      });
 </script>

But it didn't work. I thought that since the "rssfeed" part was already included in the "headline" aggregator code, I wouldn't need to define the function in the new title code?

Comment: Update your question with the code you use to fetch the headline and it will be easier to help.

Comment: I've added it, sorry, meant to do that earlier.

Comment: so, the code you posted adds some text to the element with id 'headline'. grab the text from that element, and add it to document.title

Comment: Sorry, how d'you mean "grab the text"? The problem is that the text is generated dynamically, so there is no set content within the "headline" DIV to grab: <div id="headline"></div>

Comment: Aren't you adding text to the div after the page loads?  After the content is set, get a copy of the text and use it to set the document title property

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it sounds like at some point you have the title you want to show in a JavaScript variable. If so, you can set the page title by assigning that to `document.title`:

```
document.title = varname;
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/uxonun)

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `document`'s title property with whatever value you want to show as a title.

`document.title = "new title";`

Answer (score -1):

Why not use plain old JavaScript to set the title?

```
document.title = $('#headline').html();
```

It can be set to the contents of your #headline elements content.

Comment: You're actually using plain javascript and jquery :o)

Comment: True, it was mostly for demonstration that he can still mix things :)

Comment: I edited my answer at the same time as @Madmartigan commented my answer. Initially, I had forgotten ".html()".

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: My comment was before the edit, but even still - you should use `text()` not `html()` for the `<title>` tag because it doesn't accept child elements.

Comment: @Madmartigan: Gotcha, sorry. And yes, I actually meant to mention that. :-)

Comment: This looks great (the simpler the better), but it doesn't seem to work. No error messages, but the page title doesn't change.