# overwrite title tag in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to alter the title tag in jquery.
tried as `$(document).attr("title", "New Title");`
but title tag in view source is not altered and changed only in browser title bar.

How to change the title in title tag in jquery

new title

Comment: `title tag in view source is not altered` it never will be. There is nothing you can do to change that.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        document.title = 'blah';
});
```

Comment: It's working the same as OP's approach..

Comment: There's no need for a document.ready handler for this

Comment: I wonder why you would say that. jQuery aim to be cross platform (except very old browsers?), isn't? @RoryMcCrossan. I couldn't find an official answer but found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4989558/863110)

Comment: I've deleted the comment already, but I didn't expect using `attr('title')` to do anything as `title` is a property of `document`, not an attribute. I assumed this was a browser implementation playing nice and making the conversion for you, but maybe jQuery does it instead.